# Change UIFont type globally respecting size and other atributtes in iOS

Tags: ios, fonts

I have an app developed for iOS6 and I am just migrating to iOS7

there's a new font used with this interface: "HelveticaNeue-Light"

I want to replace my system font to this one globally for buttons, labels, textviews, textfields to this, respecting all other attributes (if font is bold, italic, font-size...)

how can I do that

I was applying:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15.0f]];
```

but it changes size of all my fonts, if I set the size to default in zero my fonts dissappear

also tried this:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:@"HelveticaNeue-Light"]];
```

but this changes my font to a small size that's not the solution as well

thanks in advance for your support

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: I want to change the font-type of the whole app to "HelveticaNeue-Light", but just that, the other atributes (size, bold, italic) I want to keep them

Answer (score 0):

You probably need subclass UILabel and override `awakeFromNib` like below:

```
@implementation MyUILabel

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:self.font.pointSize];
}
@end
```